# Android Foursquare App Explore List Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, foursquare

[image]

I've been trying to figure out the best way to implement the interface on the picture attached. Since it's a complex UI, I'm wondering what's the best approach to make this without adding much complexity.

So, I've a few questions about how it could be done:

1. Is it a good approach (or possible) to do this using a ListView?
2. What's the best way to draw the interface they've created for each cell?
3. It seems they've added the ability to press different parts of the cell layout and behave as a button (highlighted in blue), how did they achieve that effect?

Thanks!